# Find set of solutions and terminate in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Here is my program:

```
reachable(X) :- start(X).
reachable(X) :- link(Y, X), reachable(Y).

start(london).

link(london, paris).
link(paris, london).
link(london, berlin).
link(paris, berlin).
link(berlin, paris).
```

Now if I query it, I get solutions:

```
?- reachable(X).
X = london ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
X = paris ;
...
```

Why does SWI-Prolog keep finding the same solutions?

How can I fix my program to return the set of solutions then halt?

Here's what I am looking for:

```
?- reachable(X).
X = paris ;
X = london ;
X = berlin ;
No
```

---

```sh
$ swipl --version  
SWI-Prolog version 7.6.4 for amd64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use **tabled execution**:

```
% The next line is required for version 7.6.4, but is considered 
% deprecated in the latest version of the SWI-Prolog compiler!

:- use_module(library(tabling)).

% The next line prepares the predicate reachable/1 for tabled execution!

:- table reachable/1.

reachable(X) :- start(X).
reachable(X) :- link(Y, X), reachable(Y).

start(london).

link(london, paris).
link(paris, london).
link(london, berlin).
link(paris, berlin).
link(berlin, paris).
```

Example:

```
?- reachable(X).
X = berlin ;
X = paris ;
X = london.
```